# How neural networks/ML could help for micro service?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, microservices, network-monitoring

I am wondering whether neural networks could help in monitoring the user request for micro services and also for monolithic service which will improve the performance of the productivity. I need a detailed advice about my query.

I have got this to know when reading [this](https://techbeacon.com/enterprise-it/how-ancestry-used-ai-optimize-its-microservices-apps) article. I am also interested in any other ideas that ML could help micro services or in monitoring server.

Comment: If you use them in a way that's productive then certainly, but that's highly subjective to the variables you have with your setup/environment. No one can really answer that for you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  StackOverflow is a knowledge base for *specific* programming problems -- not a research discussion forum.

Answer (score 1):

It depends ... on what you want to achieve. ML/"AI" is typically used to predict a specific outcome based on existing data. So, if there is historical data which indicate that the state if the system is {relaxed|critical}, you might get an idea when to act, before "critical" is reached. But then again, it appears to be be an overkill of you can simply just monitor your resources and define a threshold, when more resources need to be applied (cloud service provider scale on demand).

If you are thinking about anomaly detection, here is where ML/"AI" might help. But: you need to have relevant data to actually train a useful net.

My tip: check for service providers like datadog and check what they have in store for you. Training, evaluating and putting a neural net is not a trivial task.

Comment: Great answer. Looks like the article shared by OP is targeted on optimizing container and deployment configs - a great example of a targeted area where you can establish data to train your models.

OP may also want to look into [AI Ops](https://thenewstack.io/what-is-aiops-and-why-you-should-care/) as a general category.

Comment: The article was not very interesting, as the author did not even bother to ask the question: can our “AI” outperform resource manager like Mesos or Kubernetes? With all the elastic provisioning of cloud services, they took the route of going full “AI” without indicating the ROI of the decision. He just indicates that the decision was well planned, executed and outperforms CSP - but I see no reason, to not think it is just a marketing blog post. Never trust a post about "AI" that does not post evaluation metrics.